# Link styles for hover

Tags: html, css

I am working on some side buttons for a project and would like the link the hover styles for both elements, but am not sure how to go about this. In the example below if I highlight the link name (search) it rolls over and changes to a red text and if I highlight the image, it changes to the rollover image as expected. However what I would like to achieve is to link both so when I hover over the icon the link changes to red as well and vice versa.

```css
#linkchoice{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
#image{
    height:75px;
    background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/P5nvVtPt/search-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:75px 75px;
    background-position:center;
  } 
#linkname{
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;
  } 
#image:hover{
    background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/0jmDrrbB/search-icon-white.png);
  } 
#linkname:hover{
    color:#EB0307;
  }
```

```html
<div id='linkchoice'>
    <div id='image'></div>
    <div id='linkname'>Search</div>
</div>
```

I have made a JSFiddle as well here

https://jsfiddle.net/bzsvgwp8/

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/bzsvgwp8/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update your css from

```
#image:hover {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/0jmDrrbB/search-icon-white.png);
}

#linkname:hover {
  color: #EB0307;
}
```

to

```
#linkchoice:hover #image {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/0jmDrrbB/search-icon-white.png);
}

#linkchoice:hover #linkname {
  color: #EB0307;
}
```

You will see the combined  hover effect !

Answer (score 0):

The first solution could be to use the hover on the parent div:

```css
#linkchoice {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
#image{
    height:75px;
    background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/P5nvVtPt/search-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:75px 75px;
    background-position:center;
  } 
#linkname{
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;
  } 
#linkchoice:hover #image {
    background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/0jmDrrbB/search-icon-white.png);
  } 
#linkchoice:hover #linkname {
    color:#EB0307;
  }
```

```html
<div id='linkchoice'>
    <div id='image'></div>
    <div id='linkname'>Search</div>
</div>
```

in the second solution you can simplify the html using a single div, in this way:

```css
#linkchoice{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
#linkname{
    height:75px;
    background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/P5nvVtPt/search-icon.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:75px 75px;
    background-position:top;
    padding-top:75px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align:center;
  } 
#linkname:hover{
    background-image:url(https://i.postimg.cc/0jmDrrbB/search-icon-white.png);
    color:#EB0307;
  }
```

```html
<div id='linkchoice'>
    <div id='linkname'>Search</div>
</div>
```